# Docker exec command is very slow

Tags: docker, docker-exec

I have built docker container system where container contains a command line application. I pass arguments and run the application using docker exec command from another application.

When I run the command line application from inside docker, it takes 0.003s to run.

`$ time comlineapp "hello"`

But when I run it from outside docker using docker exec, it takes 0.500s

`$ time docker exec comline app "hello"`

So clearly docker exec takes lot of time. We need any help to reduce the time as much as possible for docker exec command.

Here is the docker file

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

RUN adduser --disabled-password --gecos "" newuser

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install time && \
    apt-get -y install gcc mono-mcs && \
    apt-get install pmccabe && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

all required softwares are already installed.

Comment: Can you please share your dockerfile? Do you install software when the container is started or do any other operations at container-startup before starting the app?

Comment: I have ypdated question with the docker file details. All required softwares are already installed. The application I was talking is gcc which I call from outside.

Comment: Have similar concern, however I am getting only 170ms overhead. I do not have any idea yet, but I run strace ( `strace -ttt -T -f docker exec ...`), and it yields interesting hints. Additionally I've learned that `docker` CLI is actually using HTTP protocol to access docker engine, so this may also be the reason of the overhead.

Comment: @Kuchara did you get any further on this?

Comment: This is answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64894654/is-there-a-way-to-speed-up-docker-exec/64895568#64895568

Answer (score 2):

When you send a request from outside docker, there’s (multiple) API requests over a unix socket and lots of extra setup for the process itself such as applying a seccomp profile, setting namespaces, dropping privileges, etc.
The proper way to leverage docker is to create a service inside it and then have the endpoints take care of these. A simple python service should cater to this. We changed the same in our platform and saved 1000s of ms post that.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I discovered a problem running `journalctl -u docker.service | tail -n 50` which threw the following error:

> level=error msg="failed to get longest-active member" error="failed to find longest active peer"

It was fixed by leaving the Docker swarm with the command `docker swarm leave` and starting it again with `docker swarm init`